# newcommand about array

Tags: macros

```
$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a+b=c\\
c+d=e
\end{array}
\right.
$
```

I define a macro command for it.

```
\newcommand{\curleq}[2]{\left\{\begin{array}{#1}{#2}\end{array}\right.}
```

When I type

```
$\curleq{l}{a+b=c\\c+d=e}$
```

Latex reports error: "Extra }, or forgotten $."

I wonder if anyone can help me solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: (Yes, I can see @Werner's answer). Package `amsmath` has an environment `cases`, which might be useful in a future.

Comment: Thank @PrzemysławScherwentke for broadening my horizon. Probably I will use cases soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `\curleq` is placed inside a braced group. And, since groups can't span cells *or* rows inside an `array` (or `tabular`), LaTeX reports an error. Just remove the braced group around the second argument `#2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\curleq}[2]{%
  \left\{\begin{array}{#1}#2\end{array}\right.}
\begin{document}
$\curleq{l}{a+b=c\\c+d=e}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Werner. Thank you for re-editing and perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: One can do away with the curly braces around `#1` as well, right?

Comment: @Mico: Technically, yes. But in general you could call `\curleq{lr}{...}` which would cause `r` to be the first entry of the array's first cell if you do not enclose `#1` in braces.

Comment: Hello, @Mico, your suggestion is only true for my current example. If I want $\curleq{ll}{a+b=c&x>0\\c+d=e&x<0}$, then the curly braces around #1 are required.

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. I had indeed focused to much on the example given by the OP.